# One Time Download Links and large files

Tags: php, time, download

I'm using this script:

http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/creating-one-time-download-links/

to allow users download files (one time). Everything works fine with small files. Now i'm trying to do the same but with larger file 1.2 GB. Instead of forcing user to download file, script show off the relative patch to the file! Is there any way to modify the script or its a fault of the server configuration?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the code i think it fails on large files due to memory limitation. Script reads the whole file in memory via `file_get_contents()` before sending it. I suspect, >1Gb files **will** cause the problems with memory.
Try to replace following lines in download.php script:

```
            //get the file content
            $strFile = file_get_contents($strDownload);

            //set the headers to force a download
            header("Content-type: application/force-download");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 

filename=\"".str_replace(" ", "_", $arrCheck['file'])."\"");

                    //echo the file to the user
                    echo $strFile;
```

to:

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($strDownload));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($strDownload));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($strDownload);
```

This may be help.

Note from manual: *readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own*

Comment: Thanks,but didnt help... Small files downloading fine but in a case of big ones, display File not found